# Struggling to get a simple function running from command line

Tags: python, input, terminal

I'm trying to get the below function running from the command line by simply using

```
python filename.py
```

However, it isn't doing what I want.

Could someone please help me out with this? I'm sure I'm missing something very simple...

```
 inFile = ""
 inFile = raw_input("Enter the File Name: ")
 x = open(inFile, 'w')

 def summation(x):
     sum = 0
     for i in x:
         sum = sum + i
     return sum

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     print(summation(x))
```

Hopefully it's fairly self explanatory what I'm trying to achieve, but in case it's not...

I'm asking for a `raw_input`; this will be a text file full of numbers (each on it's own line). The file should be fed into the variable `x` which is then used in the `summation` function. Finally, with a for loop each value is summed and the sum is returned (and printed in terminal).

Comment: "It isn't doing what I want" is not a good problem description. In your case, the program is simple enough for us to spot the obvious errors, but if your problem isn't that the program throws a `TypeError` but that it doesn't run at all because the script is the wrong directory, my answer wouldn't be helpful to you. Always provide the expected and observed results, together with any error messages you're getting, including the entire traceback, if there is one.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name as that masks the built-in `sum` function (which bruno desthuilliers uses in his answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems:

- You're opening the file in write mode. This deletes all the contents of the file. Drop the `"w"` parameter.
- You can't add strings (as read from the file) to an integer. You need to convert them to integers first: `sum += int(i)`

Also, you should close the file after you've read its contents. And the line `infile = ""` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for both pointing out the corrections and the comment you left on my original question.

Answer (score 3):

A more pythonic version...

```
def line_to_int(line):
    line = line.strip()
    if not line:
        # handles the case of empty lines
        return 0
    return int(line)

def sumfile(f):
    return sum(line_to_int(line) for line in f)

if __name__ == "__main__":
     fname = raw_input("Enter the File Name: ").strip()
     with open(fname) as f:
         print(sumfile(f))
```

or even more simple as long as you don't plan on adding error handling around the call to `int(line)` (thanks Jon Clements):

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     fname = raw_input("Enter the File Name: ").strip()
     with open(fname) as f:
         print(sum(int(line.strip() or 0) for line in f))
```

Comment: @JonClements yes indeed. Actually I first intended to add some error handling around the `int(line)` but since I didn't I could as well ditch the whole function ;)